# Laravel requests are very slow

Tags: laravel, performance, http, request

I have a laravel application but it runs very slow.

I have tried:

- caching routes, files and configs
- disabling debug mode

I checked with clockwork how time is spent on my requests and these points take the most time:

- Application initialisation. (2770 ms)
- Framework booting. (1654 ms)
- Framework running. (6573 ms)

The database takes only a small fraction of the time compared to these, can someone tell me how i can make these faster? 10 seconds for a simple login request seems unreasonable

[clockwork post requests to login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bpio.png)

What the login does is the following

[login flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpT9L.png)

Returns a token if there is any (doesn't seem to work for some reason)
Or creates a new access token for the user

I hope you can help :)

Comment: On what environment is this? VM running on an old laptop with 4 gigs of RAM? Cause then these times are nothing weird.

Comment: what php version are you running?

Comment: Simply running in docker on my 2013 macbook with 8 gb ram. php version 7.4.3

Comment: Docker with php-fpm or mod-php for apache? I run Laradock with php-fpm on my 2019 i7 (on Windows though) and my performance is not a lot better than yours.

Comment: Just checked i have 3 cores and 3gb of rams allocated for docker. That is a mysql instance, laravel and vue frontend altogether

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Never found put the exact problem unfortunately